# Udacity Prob Set 1 How to Use Git and Github diff

Tags: git, github

Here's the Problem Set 1 from Udacity Git and Github: 
Suppose you had a file, called file.txt, and you made a copy of this file, named it updated.txt and made some changes to it. Next, suppose you ran diff -u file.txt updated.txt.

The contents of the original file and the output of the diff are below. Given this information, it is possible to reconstruct what the final contents of updated.txt must have been. On the next screen, enter these contents.

```
Contents of original file.txt
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

These letters are stand-ins for the actual lines of the file. For example, this file could be a recipe, and the lines could be ingredients. Or the file could be a code file, and each letter could stand for a line of code.

```
Output of diff -u
--- file.txt    2014-12-03 16:27:41.000000000 -0500
+++ updated.txt 2014-12-03 16:28:11.000000000 -0500
@@ -2,4 +2,6 @@
 B
+$
 C
-D
+#
+%
 E
```

Just like the letters, the symbols are stand-ins for actual lines.

The contents of updated.txt must have been

```
A
B
$
C
#
%
E
F
```

The lines with plus signs in the diff output were added, meaning they were in updated.txt but not file.txt, and the lines with minus signs were removed, meaning they were in file.txt but not updated.txt. Any other lines were unchanged.

Starting from the original file, adding a dollar sign below line B, removing line D, and adding a pound sign and a percent sign above line E gives the file contents shown above.

Here are my questions: 
`diff -u` shows 3 deletions except it displays only '-D'... not '-A' or '-F'... those two letters are simply missing from `diff -u`. However, updated.txt includes 'A' and 'F'...they're not deleted.

Why?

Comment: Can you demonstrate what reasoning you've already worked through?  This website isn't intended to give answers to homework-ish questions without clear effort shown and especially when they are so specific as to be unlikely to help a broader audience than the asker alone.  Please visit the help center for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Oh, so why don't you go and say that to everyone who's asked questions about K&R problems?! People like you are the problem; I'm looking for an answer to a problem I've clearly outlined.